# How to use Twitter4j to show tweets

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter4j, tweets

I have followed this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/twitter-api-on-your-java-application.html and did the exact same thing. But I am getting an error which is shown below. Am I missing something? Should I be setting some permissions in any file? I have checked in many places but still couldn't fix this. Please help

```
Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials   
(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set 
valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
error - Not authorized
request - /1/statuses/user_timeline.json?     
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ced778ef-115a04e4], statusCode=401, retryAfter=-1,   
rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remainingHits=145, hourlyLimit=150, 
resetTimeInSeconds=1362901, secondsUntilReset=1235, resetTime=Sun Mar 10 13:15:51 IST  
2013}, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:85)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1895)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getUserTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:254)
at com.jdwb.twitterapi.tweet.main(tweet.java:33)
```

---

```
 public class tweet {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
         Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

         ResponseList < Status > a = twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1, 5));
         for (Status b: a) {
             System.out.println(b.getText());
         }
     }
 }



-------------------------Properties file-------------

debug=true
oauth.consumerKey=***************
oauth.consumerSecret=***********
oauth.accessToken=*******************
oauth.accessTokenSecret=***********************
```

---

```
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]status: 401 Unauthorized
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]x-ratelimit-remaining: 143
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]content-encoding: gzip
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]date: Sun, 10 Mar 2013 09:11:26 GMT
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]x-ratelimit-reset: 1362908664
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]x-transaction: 58f6c286bb1aa6de
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]pragma: no-cache
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
[Sun Mar 10 14:41:26 IST 2013]{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?include_rts=true&include_entities=true&include_my_retweet=1&count=5&page=1","error":"Not authorized"}

 Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials   
 (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have 
 set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
 error - Not authorized
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have not got your authorization set up correctly

have a look [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html#fileconfiguration) for how to set up the properties file.

you need to sign up to the [twitter dev](https://dev.twitter.com/) to get your API keys so that you can fill in the information that you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have obtained the keys from twitter. I have added a twitter4j.properties file to my project and have added the     keys as shown in that link. Now i am getting this error "consumer key/secret pair already set"

Comment: are you setting the keys in the properties file and in the code as well?